# How to pop up apple pay like UI when my app shows annual subscription purchasing UI in iOS11

Tags: in-app-purchase, subscription, ios11, applepay

I'm using iOS 11 and I'd like to developing annual subscription purchasing logic in my app. But since upgrade to iOS 11 today. I newly popup ui looks like apple pay. But my own app doesn't show that UI just shows UIAlert style popup.

Would someone help me which frameworks or kit should I use in order to display apple style purchasing popup?

[App Store Subscription purchase UI - looks like a apple pay style UI - I'd like use that UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSvXH.png)

[my alert style popup when click purchase, I want to change it to picture 1 style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndswt.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The popup shows for dev builds and builds downloaded from TestFlight. If you build for production you'll see the new purchase UI.